# PSQL asks for a password

Tags: postgresql, authentication

When I pipe the output of `raster2pgsql` to `psql -d ais -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432` it asks for a password.

How can I supply it the password on the command line?

Comment: It's moderately dangerous to database integrity to use the `postgres` user for data loading. I suggest you use best practice and create a different login user for data loading.

Comment: You're piping to `psql` this has nothing to do with PostGIS. It's a generic postgresql question

Answer (score 1):

You must supply a password if the user account needs a password. You are loading the data as the "postgres" user so you need to supply its password.

This can be done as an environmental variable in the PSQL command. Using `PGPASSWORD=yourpass` before the psql command

So:

```
raster2pgsql.exe -s 3035 -C -M -I C:\AIS_DEF\DEF\FINAL\test_baleari\grid_baleari3.tif grid_baleari | PGPASSWORD=yourpass psql -d ais -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432
```

However this may not be the best way to do it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523019/postgresql-scripting-psql-execution-with-password

If you don't want it to prompt for passwords at all, this can be done through the `pg_hba.conf` file.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83164/remove-password-requirement-for-user-postgres

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Could I ask something more about how to set the size of raster? the number of cells is 55813 (1x1 km each cell) and I dont' know where should be specified it

Comment: That is read from the raster metadata or worldfile. For a geotiff it is embedded in the image after georeferencing. If the answer solved your issue, you should accept it as correct by ticking the green tick mark next to the upvote button.

Answer (score 0):

A few points,

1. This has nothing to do with PostGIS (the geospatial extension). It's a problem for PostgreSQL and better suited for DBA.SE.
2. You shouldn't log in as `postgresql` except to create your initial users and database.
3. For the underlying problem.

   1. You can use the environmental variable `PGPASSWORD`
   2. You can configure your `pg_hba.conf` to `trust` (or `peer`) and it won't ask for you password when you connect locally.